# Firebase Analytics Won't StreamView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm scratching my head a few hours now over this "problem". It should be so simple.

I want to add simple firebase analytics library to my existing android project.

What I did:

- Included dependencies in my build.gradle (com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1)
- Applied google services plugin after dependecies bracket
- in onCreate of my MainActivity called the following code:

  ```
  FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setCurrentScreen(this, "Main Activity", null).
  ```

At this point as I understand the streamview in my console should be showing 1 user in the last 30 minutes. But I get 0 users. no activity detected.

I've made sure that google-services.JSON file is included in the project (Android Studio compiles without warnings) and that the package name is the same everywhere (build.gradle, manifest, firebase console).

Also, I've tried sample project from GitHub and it also won't work (detect any activity in the last 30 minutes).

I'm primarily a programmer working in Unity and I didn't have any problems there -setting up the firebase SDK.

But I'm sure I'm still missing something.. so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try [enabling verbose logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log) to confirm that events are being reported.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I now did as you said and I think events are beings sent to Google servers.I get a lot of event messages being recorded and scheduled for upload. I also looked to my firebase console and I got 1 streamview (my device), and I have no clue how. I only did what you've said. I hope this is it. Thank you..

Comment: You can also try [DebugView](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7201382?hl=en&utm_id=ad&authuser=0) instead of StreamView